# Lazarus: stacking images, paint order

Tags: lazarus, timage

I want to design a simple game (lazarus 1.8.4) with an image as playing field and some figures (transparent images) over it, created on runtime. So typically more than one images are at the same position. How can I make sure, that the figures are above the playing field?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you want a quality answer, you should provide as much informations as possible, show what you have tried so far and point at a specific problem. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And what information do you miss? There is nothing I could try.

Comment: I miss effort on your side. Did you have a look at the LCL Docs? Btw to make stuff short, the function you are lookin for is `BringToFront` (the opposite is `SendToBack`)

Comment: what do you think? Of course I did. And I used search engines with many different search words. You killed my thank you in advance but you want at the other hand, that I add needless information? Everyone should have read all relevant information and searched for it. So did I!

Comment: There is no need to be agressive. Its common on this site that stuff like "thank you" is discouraged and edited away. Get used to it. Imho describing what the problem is and showing effort (and maybe example code that we see what we are dealing with) is not "needless informations", but thats on you to provide it or not. But it would increase your chance of getting an answer. Currently I can only advice you to use the `BringToFront` method, but as I dont know what the **specific** problem is, that is just looking into the chrystal ball. So long and thanks for all the fish.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was the answer I needed. Bring to front is a method of TControl, so I lost sight of it. My Problem is not that specific as I thought. Your chrystal ball is much better than you think :) Sorry if it sounded aggressive to you, this was not my mind.

Comment: all good, glad it worked out. Ill post it as an answer, it would be nice if you accept it so others might find the answer

Comment: of course I do, many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TControl` has a function called `BringToFront` which will move the Control to the first position in the Z-Axis (the opposing function would be `SendToBack`). As `TImage` is derived from `TControl` the function applies to `TImage` as well.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot